# How to capture Ctrl key press and release on SWT ListViewer

Tags: java, swt, rcp

I'm trying to do a multiple selection of elements on SWT ListViewer based on Ctrl key press. I want to differentiate between selection using Ctrl key and simple selection on the ListViewer. I don't find a way on how to see if the Ctrl key is pressed or released. I don't see a helpful Listener addition to that. Is there a way to know the selection using key press and release on SWT ListViewer.
Here is the sample code I tried.

```
public class DummyListViewer {

private ListViewer dummyViewer;

    public DummyListViewer (Composite parent) {
            dummyViewer = createListViewer(parent);
        }

        private ListViewer createListViewer(Composite parent) {
            GridData data = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.LEFT, false, false);
            ScrolledComposite scrolledParent = (ScrolledComposite) createScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            final ListViewer dummyViewer= new ListViewer(scrolledParent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL| SWT.MULTI);
            dummyViewer.getList().addKeyListener(new CtrlKeyListener());
            dummyViewer.setContentProvider(new ListViewerContentProvider());
            dummyViewer.setLabelProvider(new ListViewerLabelProvider());
            scrolledParent.setContent(dummyViewer.getControl());
            scrolledParent.setMinSize(dummyViewer.getControl().computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
            dummyViewer.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, true));
            return dummyViewer;
        }

        private Composite createScrolledComposite(Composite parent, int style) {
            ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
            scrolledComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
            GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
            gridData.widthHint = 400;
            gridData.heightHint = 700;
            scrolledComposite.setLayoutData(gridData);
            scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
            scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
            return scrolledComposite;
        }

        public void setInput(List<Object> input) {
            filterViewer.setInput(input);
        }

        private class ListViewerContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {

            @Override
            public void dispose() {

            }

            @Override
            public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {

            }

            @Override
            public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
                if (inputElement instanceof List) {
                    return ((List)inputElement).toArray();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }

        private ColumnViewerFilter filter;



        private class ColumnViewerFilter extends ViewerFilter {

            String value=""; //$NON-NLS-1$

            /**
             * Constructor for ColumnViewerFilter to set the String on which
             * the viewer has to be filtered on.
             * @param value - String on which
             * the viewer has to be filtered on.
             */
            public ColumnViewerFilter(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element) {
                if (value != null && value instanceof String && element instanceof String) {
                    if (value.equals(element))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        }

        private class ListViewerLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider {

            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof String)
                    return (String)element;
                return null;
            }

        }



        private boolean CtrlkeyPressed = false;
        private class CtrlKeyListener implements KeyListener{

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.keyCode == SWT.CTRL)
                CtrlkeyPressed = true;

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
               if (e.keyCode == SWT.CTRL)
                CtrlkeyPressed = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you do a setInput on the ListViewer.

Comment: As I'm creating  DummyListViewer object elsewhere , I setting the input after creating  DummyListViewer object. But never mind, the code seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to key event using `addKeyListener` on the `List` control contained in the `ListViewer`:

```
viewer.getList().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e)
  {
    if (e.keyCode == SWT.CTRL)
      // TODO control pressed
   }

  @Override
  public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e)
  {
    if (e.keyCode == SWT.CTRL)
      // TODO control release
  }

});
```

Note that on some platforms multiple selection does not use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. On the Mac the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key is used (`SWT.COMMAND`).

Comment: Works for me. Edit your question and add your code.